Annotated version for Hibernate XML mapping throws error: not-null property references a null or transient value
I am trying to upgrade from Spring  4.3.x and Hibernate 3.6.x to Spring 5.3.x and Hibernate 5.3.x
previously my mapping was in XML and now I want to convert them to annotation.
For the below mapping I am not sure if I have done the annotated conversion correctly:
 <join table="JOIN_TABLE" schema="ORACLE" inverse="true" optional="true">
      <key column="CLASS_A_UID"/>
      <many-to-one name="fieldB" column="CLASS_B_UID" not-null="true"/>
 </join>
            

 <set name="fieldA" table="JOIN_TABLE" schema="ORACLE" fetch="join" cascade="save-update">
      <key column="CLASS_B_UID" />
      <many-to-many column="CLASS_A_UID" unique="true" class="PojoClassA" />
 </set>

I tried converting like below.
@ManyToOne( targetEntity = PojoClassB.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER )
@JoinTable( name = "JOIN_TABLE", schema = "ORACLE",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn( name = "CLASS_A_UID" ),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn( name = "CLASS_B_UID" ) )
private PojoClassB fieldB;
    
    
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable( name = "JOIN_TABLE", schema = "oracle",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn( name = "CLASS_B_UID" ),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn( name = "CLASS_A_UID", unique = true ) )
@Cascade( CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE )
@Fetch( FetchMode.JOIN )
private SortedSet<PojoClassA> fieldA = new TreeSet<PojoClassA>();

But I am not sure if this is the correct mapping, because I get an error message:

org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value: PojoClassA.fieldA


I think previous mapping is incorrect. any suggestions are welcome. Thanks
